# find the number of ways to distribute six handouts

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, contest-math

> Fifteen freshmen are sitting in a circle around a table, but the course assistant (who remains standing) has made only six copies of today's handout. No freshman should get more than one handout, and any freshmen who doesn't get one should be able to read a neighbor's. If the freshmen are distinguishable but the handouts are not, how many ways are there to distribute the six handouts subject to the above conditions?

I think the answer is 750, and my reasoning is shown below.

We consider the sequences of 6 gap sizes between consecutive students. By the problem conditions, each sequence must consist only of the numbers 0,1,2 and sum to 9. The only possibilities up to ordering are $1,1,1,2,2,2$ and $2,2,2,2,0,1,2$. Distinct sequences are not cyclic shifts of each other because they involve at least two different numbers. Each sequence corresponds to 15 possibilities, which are the cyclic shifts of the sequences (since the freshmen are distinct while the handouts are not and cyclic shifts are distinct). So we have $\dfrac{6!}{3!3!} + \dfrac{6! }{4!} = 50$ sequences, giving $50\cdot 15 = 750$ possibilities.

> However, it seems I've overcounted possibilities due to cyclic shifts.

Comment: Consider freshmen have numbers : 1 to 15 ; You consider 111222 starting with freshman n°1 and 112221 starting with freshman n°3 are different, but it is exactly same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting a much smaller number by using a reference point.  As Lourrran has pointed out in the comments, your assumption that each of the patterns you found is distinct breaks down in a circular arrangement.

Suppose there is a seat at the northern end of the table.  Proceeding clockwise from that seat, the first person selected is either in that seat, the seat immediately to the left of that seat, or two seats to the left of the seat at the north end of the table.

**Case 1:** Suppose the person at the north end of the table is selected.

Then there are six gaps, one to the left of each selected person, as we proceed clockwise around the table from the northern end of the table.  Let $x_i$ be the number of people who are in the $i$th gap.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 9 \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_i \leq 2$, $1 \leq i \leq 6$.  Observe that at most three of the restrictions can be violated simultaneously since $4 \cdot 3 = 12 > 9$.

If there were no restrictions, a particular solution of equation $1$ corresponds to the placement of $6 - 1 = 5$ addition signs in a row of nine ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 + 1 1 + + 1 + 1 1 + 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 0$, $x_4 = 1$ $x_5 = x_6 = 2$. The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can place five addition signs in a row of nine ones which is
$$\binom{9 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{14}{5}$$
From these, we must subtract those cases in which at least one restriction is violated.

*A variable exceeds* $2$:  Suppose it is $x_1$.  Then $x_1' = x_1 - 3$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 3$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 and simplifying yields
$$x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 6 \tag{2}$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{6 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{11}{5}$$
solutions.  Since there are six variables that could have violated the restriction, we must subtract
$$\binom{6}{1}\binom{11}{5}$$
from the total.

However, if we do so, we will have subtracted too much.  That is because we have subtracted each case in which two variables exceed $2$ twice, once for each way we could have designated one of those variables as the variable that exceeds $2$.  We only want to subtract those cases once, so we must add them to the total.

*Two of the variables each exceed* $2$:  Suppose that they are $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Then $x_1' = x_1 - 3$ and $x_2' = x_2 - 3$ are nonnegative integers.  Substituting $x_1' + 3$ for $x_1$ and $x_2' + 3$ for $x_2$ in equation $1$ and simplifying yields
$$x_1' + x_2' + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 3 \tag{3}$$
Equation $3$ is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{3 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{8}{5}$$
solutions.  Since there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select which two of the variables exceed $2$, there are
$$\binom{6}{2}\binom{8}{5}$$
such cases.

If we add that amount to the total, we will have added too much.  That is because we first subtracted the cases in which three variables each exceed $2$
three times, once for each way we could have designated one of those three variables as the one that exceeds $2$, and then added them three times, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways we could have designated two of the three variables as the pair of variables which each exceed $2$.  Consequently, we have not subtracted those cases in which three of the variables exceed $2$.

*Three of the variables exceed* $2$:  Suppose they are $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$.  Then $x_1' = x_1 - 3$, $x_2' = x_2 - 3$, and $x_3' = x_3 - 3$ are nonnegative integers.  Substituting $x_1' + 3$ for $x_1$, $x_2' + 3$ for $x_2$, and $x_3' + 3$ for $x_3$ in equation $1$ and simplifying yields
$$x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + x_4' + x_5' + x_6' = 0 \tag{4}$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with one solution.  Since there are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to select which three of the six variables exceed $2$, there are
$$\binom{6}{3}$$
such cases.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), there are
$$\binom{14}{5} - \binom{6}{1}\binom{11}{5} + \binom{6}{2}\binom{8}{5} - \binom{6}{3}$$
cases in which the person in the seat at the northern end of the table is selected.

**Case 2:**  The person at the north end of the table is not selected, but the person to the immediate left of that person is selected.

Since the person at the north end of the table is not selected, $x_6$ is either $1$ or $2$.

If $x_6 = 1$, then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 8 \tag{5}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_i \leq 2$, $1 \leq i \leq 5$.

Applying the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle yields
$$\binom{8 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{5 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{2 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{12}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{9}{4} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{4}$$
solutions to equation $5$ that satisfy the stated restrictions.

If $x_6 = 2$, then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 7 \tag{6}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_i \leq 2$, $1 \leq i \leq 5$.

Applying the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle yields
$$\binom{7 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{4 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{1 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{11}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{8}{4} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{4}$$
solutions to equation $6$ that satisfy the stated restrictions.

**Case 3:** The person at the north end of the table and the person immediately to the left of the north end of the table are not selected, but the person two seats to the left of the north end of the table is selected.

Since the person at the north end of the table and the person to the immediate left of that person are not selected, $x_6 = 2$.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 7 \tag{7}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_i \leq 2$, $1 \leq i \leq 5$.

By symmetry, equation $7$ has
$$\binom{11}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{8}{4} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{4}$$
solutions that satisfy the stated restrictions.

**Total:**  Since these three cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of ways the teacher can distribute the handouts so that every student can read the handout is
$$\binom{14}{5} - \binom{6}{1}\binom{11}{5} + \binom{6}{2}\binom{8}{5} - \binom{6}{3} + \binom{12}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{9}{4} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{4} + 2\left[\binom{11}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{8}{4} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{4}\right]$$